# If I deploy my react app, will the link to a localhost still be valid, or will I also need to host the localhost app?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, localhost, next.js, strapi

Basically the heading. I have a strapi app at localhost:1337 which I will fetch in React. I'm not very sure how localhost works, and therefore I want to know if the path will still be relevant when I deploy the react app.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your react.js app on any server your url named http://localhost:1337/Dashboard
will be changed. In it http://localhost:1337/ is the base url or domain name. Which will change the server to the new one.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow sorry. Does that mean localhost:1337 can still be fetched? Or will it be obsolete once the react app is deployed?

Comment: localhost:1337 will be obselete and server will add new domain name

Comment: Oh so the code to fetch will automatically swap to a new domain name, then everything will work as normal?

Answer (score 0):

your code will maintain same value for that API and you will have to re-build your code each time you change your API, (most of people use low cost hosting provider which allow only port 80 to be used) my advice is to move your endpoit (backend url) outside your code in a json, .env file ... but what will work on most of platform is a variable defined in your public/index.html (not a best pratice but it will work) ex:

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <!-- you will add this tag here it will contain your backend url -->
    <script> 
      var bakendUrl = "http://....";
    </script> 
    <!-- some other code here -->
    </head> 

    <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
   </html>
```